# How can I calculate at compiletime in c++

Tags: c++

How to calculate some mathematical expression i.e. finding factorial of n; during compiletime in c++ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082113/calculating-factorial-using-template-meta-programming

Comment: Besides template metaprogramming, you could probably use c++11 [`constexpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_-_Generalized_constant_expressions) and recursion. Unfortunately I cannot check this right now.

Comment: This is too much of a homework-style question, plus the reader was rude enough to downvote those who gave links as answers, he doesn't want do any research, he wanted it down for him..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) is a wiki article about template meta-programing in C++.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution) is another wiki article about compile-time function execution.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977715/calculating-and-printing-factorial-at-compile-time-in-c) is a SO question regarding the factorial.

Let's take the wiki xample of computing factorial in compile-time.

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
const int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
const int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
```

Since all of the arguments needed are known in the compile time (they are explicitly mentioned in `Factorial<4>`, for example), the compiler is able to generate all the needed code. After that, the `value` of the `Factorial<4>` struct will be 24 which can be later used as if you've hardcoded it yourself.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvotes please?

Comment: I guess link only answers are discouraged..

Comment: Why? They explain the question.

Comment: @mugen well the answer isn't really detailed too, and the OP doesn't show any research attempt. Not to mention this is partially a duplicate.

Comment: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) (I didn't downvote though).

Comment: I think it is better to flag questions accordingly than to answer with  half a sentence. But that is just my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the so-called template meta-programming.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) describes what it is. It has a specific example to calculate the factorial of an integer in compile-time.